# PHP ActiveRecord

Tags: php, activerecord

I have been struggling for more than two hours now trying to build a simply query that has to use the LIKE operator without success.

First attempt was to use my model with the code snippet below:

```
return self::find('all', ['conditions' => "`code` LIKE ?", "'%$searchString%'"]);
```

The code above returns nothing meanwhile when running the query manually gives me at least two records:

```
SELECT * FROM `vehicle_models` WHERE `code` LIKE "%AUD%"
```

I have also resorted to using the SQLBuilder without success as shown below:

```
$conn = ConnectionManager::get_connection("default");
$builder = new SQLBuilder($conn, static::$table_name);

echo $builder->where('`code` LIKE ?', "'%$searchString%'");
```

//echo outputs: SELECT * FROM vehicle_models WHERE `code` LIKE ?

What could I be missing with both options to using the LIKE operator in PHP ActiveRecord Library?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you:

```
return self::all(array(
    'conditions' => array(
        "code LIKE %?%", 
        $searchString
        );
);
```